# cannot log on icloud.com. 403 Forbidden

Tags: icloud, web-browser

I was trying to log on icloud.com using my Mac but a 403 forbidden page showed up after I typed my account and password. I was using Google Chrome. Currently there is no solution from what I searched. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact URL before and after login? Have you tried with a different browser (the question is tagged [web-browser] instead of specifically [google-chrome])?

Comment: This suggestion may sound a little superstitious, and it may be. I would quit Chrome, restart the Mac, then try again using a different browser before launching Chrome.

Comment: @grg The URL didn't change. It was always https://www.icloud.com/

Comment: @Trellis I tried that but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error disappeared after I upgraded my Mac OS system.